# Best practice for representing floating infinity in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

Since a very large floating value can be represented as follows:
`sys.float_info.max` and `float("inf")`.

Is one better than the other? If yes, under what circumstances?

Or which is one more preferred for scientific computing?

Comment: Those are not the same number.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely not the first:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

That's the largest *finite* float.

You're missing the preferred method ;-)

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.inf
inf
```

Note also:

```py
>>> math.nan
nan
```

Answer (score 2):

This should indirectly tell you everything you need to know:

```
>>> float('inf') > sys.float_info.max
True
>>> float('inf') <= sys.float_info.max
False
```

Comment: bit updated the question. 
intention is to understand which one is preferred more and under what circumstances in the context of scientific computing

Comment: @letsBeePolite I answered the question as I did because you know your application better than I ever will, and only you can decide which behavior is appropriate.  If it were me I'd always go for actual infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider NumPy, which is likely to come into play if you're doing scientific computing. According to [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html), NumPy has

- `numpy.inf`  IEEE 754 Positive infinity
- `numpy.NINF` IEEE 754 Negative infinity

It's odd that one is all lower case and one is all caps.

There are also several helper functions, e.g.

- `numpy.isinf`     which elements are + or - infinity
- `numpy.isposinf`  which elements are + infinity
- `numpy.isneginf`  which elements are - infinity
- `numpy.isfinite`  which elements do not belong to NaN or infinity

Unless you need crazy arbitrary high precision, NumPy could be your best choice.

**Edit:**

For crazy arbitrary high precision, there is also the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#special-values) module, which provides

- Decimal('Infinity'), Decimal('inf'), Decimal('+inf') for + infinity
- Decimal('-Infinity'), Decimal('-inf') for + infinity

Decimal seems to not be case sensitive at all and +Infinity does not require a + sign.